# MySQLdb python insert row or increment count on column if exists

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I have a simple table in MySQL which looks like this:

### > ID | username | count

What I want to achieve using python is:

- Add username to table, if does not exist, and set count to 1.
- Whenever the username exists, increment count by 1.

What is the best approach for this using MySQLdb in python 2.7

Of course I could do this by querying for username, then if exists update count, but maybe there is a better way of doing this.

Thanks !

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15383973/322909) will be of use to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach using the link that @johnthexii provided ([demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be153/1/0)) (it is using just MySQL, so it isn't Python specific)

```
CREATE TABLE UserNames (`username` varchar(35) unique, `duplicates` int);

INSERT INTO UserNames (`username`, `duplicates`)
 VALUES ('stackoverflow.com', 0);

INSERT INTO UserNames (`username`, `duplicates`)
 VALUES ('dba.stackexchange.com/', 0)
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `duplicates` = `duplicates`+1;

INSERT INTO UserNames (`username`, `duplicates`)
 VALUES ('stackoverflow.com', 0)
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `duplicates` = `duplicates`+1;
```

Here is a breakdown of what is going on:  The `username` field is marked as unique so any attempt to insert a record with an existing username will fail at the database level.  Then the `INSERT` statement has an extra

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `duplicates` = `duplicates`+1
```

This tells MySQL that instead of failing the INSERT to just take the `duplicates` column and increment by one.  When you run the three INSERT commands you will see two records, `stackoverflow.com` has a `duplicates` value of 1, while `dba.stackexchange.com` has a `duplicates` value of 0.