# Mysql query to update row if exists?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I need an If, then, else query in mysql,
tried out the below,

```
if exists( select * from data_table where user_id =1 and link_id = 1) then update data_table set is_view = 1 where user_id = 1 else insert into data_table...
```

what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL - IF EXISTS UPDATE ELSE INSERT INTO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383852/sql-if-exists-update-else-insert-into)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only need to do this in mysql, then search insert on duplicate key. Or you can use a stored procedure. Check [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into data_table (user_id, link_id, other_column)
values (1, 1, 'value to insert or uodate')
on duplicate key update  other_column='value to insert or update';
```