# how to use if exist else in mysql statement

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

i'm trying to write a if exists else sql which will further use in c# winform with mysql, here is the test

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 from products where entity_id=1) select * from products;
```

i ran above sql in adminer but there is a error message, 
Syntax error near 'select * from products' at line 1

Anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: what should the query do?

Comment: insert if not exists else update

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383852/sql-if-exists-update-else-insert-into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should create a UNIQUE constraint on the columns.

```
ALTER TABLE products  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_products UNIQUE (column1, column2, etc..)
```

Then just insert the data:

```
INSERT INTO products (column1, column2, etc..) VALUES(value1, value2, etc..) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column1 = newValue, column2 = newValue2;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  DELIMITER $$

        DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `verifyExist` $$
            CREATE PROCEDURE `verifyExist`()
            BEGIN
           IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 from products where entity_id=1) THEN 
            select * from products;
          END IF;
    END$$

        DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This is the syntax for mssql not mysql

Comment: Edit my answer with the create procedure.