# MYSQL update data from another table if exist else insert

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, mysql-python

I'm using mysql database. I'm having a main table with id as primary key with (auto increment,not null, unique) constraints.

---

**My main table :**

[image: sample of my table]

---

**In secondary table i have the same fields but without id column**

[image]

---

Now i need to update the main table from the secondary table with the following condition.

if a user data exists in main table, it should be replaced with secondary table data and new rows should add. (example: 1st row of user1 needs to be replaced with secondary table data , and new rows of user1 should be added in the  main table)

---

**Expected output:**

[image]

I have tried with insert...on duplicate update.
it doesn't worked ! Any help?

Comment: Post what you tried!

Comment: Similar question answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383852/sql-if-exists-update-else-insert-into

Answer (score -1):

Try the following steps.

Step 1: As you want to replace the data in main table if the user exists in the second table, first delete all the data from main table which exists in the second table

```
delete from main_table where login_name in (select login_name from second_table);
```

Step 2:

```
insert into main_table (login_name, mgr_name, ...)
select login_name, mgr_name,... from second_table
```

Here in the first step, you are deleting users which are present in the second table and in step 2, you will insert all users from second_table hence you will eventually have your existing users replaced in the main_table.

Comment: Appreciate you answer! But in your solution primary key value is going to change for all those record which will update values in main table.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it. So from the second table, if 3 records found for user1, which record will you replace in the main table? Also, you want to achieve it in python or pure SQL?

Comment: looking at screen shot @Jones Kumar wants 1st to be replaced out of  3

Comment: Yeah, I know. So there are 3 records for user1 so how would you identify that he want to replace it with 1st, 2nd or 3rd row?

Comment: i dont want the records to be replaced strictly, old data should delete and new data should be there.